# make container not take more remaining space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build something like in the snippet here:

```css
.overall-container {
  height: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;
}

.scroll-menu {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 100px; // this should be the rest of the screen height
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-menu">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem:
I want to make scroll-menu a container to scroll through, so that you cant scroll through overall-container. Header should always be visible that way.
That would mean I would need to limit scroll-menu's height someway, but I do not know how.

Comment: What remaining space do you want .scroll-menu to take up?

Comment: 'height : screen'??

Comment: @Paulie_D yes I mean the parent containers height (height: screen)

Comment: .scroll-menu is already taking up all of its parent's remaining space

Comment: @NHerwich Sorry, I am gonna edit the question. I want scroll-menu to be a seperate container to scroll trough, scroll-menu takes to much space. The question is what height should I assign to scroll-menu in order to make it take the rest of the space that is left on the screen, without making the screen but only scroll-menu scrollable.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible with pure css. Either .overall-container or .scroll-menu need to have a height value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is, use `Flexbox`. Set the parent container `overall-container` to `display: flex; height: 100vh;` and the child container `scroll-menu` to take all the available space using the `flex-grow: 1` or shorthand `flex: 1` property.

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0 } /* added to remove the default margin and padding */

.overall-container {
  height: screen;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 2px;

  /* add these lines */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 97vh;
}

.scroll-menu {
  overflow-y: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 2px;

  flex: 1; /* add this line */
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-menu">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **height: screen;** doesn't work because **screen** is not a valid property value: it is not even present in Chrome Devtools Style editor. So it might be you meant **-webkit-fill-available**, but this last one is non standard and still experimental and it kinda work, but not very well yet, so don't use it just yet, and let's hope for the future.

So you might consider to use for the continer:

```
height:100vh;
```

considering that 1vh is 1% of browser screen height or even less.

Also, for the div that contains the header, I'd suggest to use a h[1-6] or the  elements because they are the header element "semantically correct" to be used as header, but you can keep the div element if you wish.

Also in css you could use for example:

```
height: calc( 100vh - 25px );
```

the calc() css function would calculate for you the view port height (100vh)  and will subtract 25px from it. But in this case you need to know what is the element height to subtract.

```css
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0 } /* added to remove the default margin and padding */

.overall-container
{
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 89vh; /* Using here 90 instead of 100 vh, to compensate the borders thickness and padding, that you need to subtract to make them visible into the page, if you don't, the bottom border ends up hidden down the page. Decreasing or removing  border and padding (for instance by commenting the rows so you can experiment) you can increase this value up to 99 or even 100 to make the element to expand to the whole view port*/
}

.scroll-menu
{
  background: yellow;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.header, .overall-container, .scroll-menu
{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="scroll-menu">
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
    <div>Element 7</div>
    <div>Element 8</div>
    <div>Element 9</div>
    <div>Element 10</div>
    <div>Element 11</div>
    <div>Element 12</div>
    <div>Element 1</div>
    <div>Element 2</div>
    <div>Element 3</div>
    <div>Element 4</div>
    <div>Element 5</div>
    <div>Element 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nevertheless it seems to me that you want to built a menu. What about to try a little different approach with the use of details/summary html elements? ... it is just a possible alternative.

```css
details > details,
details > a
{
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>
    In line menu title (click to show sub elements) ☰
  </summary>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a> | <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a></details>

<br>

<details>
  <summary>
    Vertical menu example (click to show sub elements) ☰
  </summary>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a>
</details>

<br>

<details open>
  <summary>
    Vertical menu example (already opened, click to close) ☰
  </summary>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a>
</details>

<br>

<details>
  <summary>
    Vertical menu example with sub menu ☰
  </summary>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>

  <details>
    <summary>
      The Sub menu ☰
    </summary>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
    <a href="yourpage.html">Your Page.html</a><br>
  </details>
</details>
```

Of course you might need to style the menu as you need.

Also another valid approach is to style as sticky the element that acts as header to prevent it from scrolling with the rest: In this case you dont even need a second div:

```css
.overall-container
{
  background: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: calc(100vh - 28px);
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

h3
{
    background: red;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overall-container">
  <h3>Header</h3>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
  Menu Element n<br>
</div>
```

Notice that I have set on purpose the css of the header as red bgcolor to distinguish it from the rest to make you able to spot how the rest of the elements stay under it while scrolling them. Of course setting it as orange, the same color the container, won't be noticeable any difference.